# how can i delete records if two columns match mysql php

Tags: mysql

my problem is that I want to delete one record on my table "provicional" if "Id" and "Password" match...   i have a simple code but just work for ID and I want to delete it if both match!

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM  `provicional` WHERE  `id` IN ('3','basico')";
```

many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A not so popular way of doing this in MySQL would be:

```
DELETE FROM provicional WHERE (id, password) = (3, 'basico')
```

Note you can add more than just 2 elements in each list.

Tip: Do not use apostrophes `'` around numeric fields.

Comment: Thank you very much bro! @MostyMostacho for your help, i know its a not popular way or safe way, but its the easy one for me, i just want somethin simple later i will learn better and safer ways.... thank a lot for your help and advices :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM  `provicional` WHERE  `id` IN ('3') AND `password` IN ('basico')";
```

Comment: Tip when there is only one value to match its better to use equals operator

Comment: Since your answer nearly looks good so i already gave you your points :)